# How to loop in tabula-py data format in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tabula-py

I want to know how to extract particular table column from pdf file in python.

My code so far

```
    import tabula.io as tb
from tabula.io import read_pdf
dfs = tb.read_pdf(pdf_path, pages='all')
print (len(dfs)) [It displays 73]
```

I am able to access individual table column by doing print (dfs[2]['Section ID'])
I want to know how can I search particular column in all data frame using for loop.

I want to do something like this

```
for i in range(len(dfs)):
    if (dfs[i][2]) == 'Section ID ' //(This gives invalid syntax)
    print dfs[i]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only one dataframe with `Section ID` name (or are interested only in the first dataframe with this column) you can iterate over the list returned by `read_pdf`, check for the column presence with `in df.columns` and `break` when a match is found.

```py
import tabula.io as tb
from tabula.io import read_pdf
df_list = tb.read_pdf(pdf_path, pages='all')

for df in df_list:
    if 'Section ID' in df.columns:
        break
print(df)
```

If you may have multiple dataframes with the `Section ID` column, you can use list comprehension filter and get a *list* of dataframes with that column name.

```py
dfs_section_id = [df for df in df_list if 'Section ID' in df.columns]
```